# C# design related query (better refactoring)

Tags: c#

I am working on a functionality where I feel there is room for improvement.

***Scenario:***

I have a different types of buttons in an physical instrument. Each button type has a certain functionality (say volume up or volume down etc).

I have got a task to implement - getting functionality of a new button type depending on certain actions (short press, medium press and long press). I followed the approach that is used to getting functionality for other button types.

***End result:***

End result should be that the new button type class should return all the functionalities that the button supports.

***Implementation:***

I have created a class "*InstrumentButtonType4*" inheriting from "*InstrumentButtonBase*".

"*InstrumentButtonType4*" class has a method *GetButtonTypeFunctionalities()*, that first checks
if button is available and enable.

Then adds button functionality depending of actions.

Now I have three actions short press, long press and medium press.

***Main logic :-***

I get the current value stored in the instrument for each of the actions "*int shortPress = _instrumenrData.GetValue(3);*" and call a static Mapper "*InstructionButtonFunctionalityMapper*" to get the corresponding functionality mapped to the given "*shortPress*" value.

***Want to refactor in a better way***

I want to improve these three methods if it can be written in a better way

1. AddFunctionalityForShortPress()
2. AddFunctionalityForMediumPress()
3. AddFunctionalityForVeryLongPress()

Can the logic in these three methods be written in some better design. Can we eliminate somehow the Mapper and make the
implementation simpler/flexible and scallable?

I have pasted the whole class code below. *Code can be compiled in a console application.* 
Your expert advice will really help me to learn and achive this in a better way.

```
public interface IInstrumentData
{
    int GetValue(int location);
}

public abstract class InstrumentButtonBase
{
   public abstract  bool IsAvailable();
   public  abstract bool IsEnable();

   public abstract IDictionary<ButtonType, IDictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality>> GetButtonTypeFunctionalities();
}


public class InstrumentButtonType4 : InstrumentButtonBase
{
    private readonly IInstrumentData _instrumenrData;

    public InstrumentButtonType4(IInstrumentData instrumenrData)
    {
        _instrumenrData = instrumenrData;
    }

    public override IDictionary<ButtonType, IDictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality>> GetButtonTypeFunctionalities()
    {
        var instrumentMaps = new Dictionary<ButtonType, IDictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality>>();
        var buttonFunctionality = new Dictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality>();

        if (!IsAvailable() && !IsEnable())
        {
            return instrumentMaps;
        }

        AddButtonFunctionality(buttonFunctionality);
        instrumentMaps.Add(ButtonType.Volume, buttonFunctionality);

        return instrumentMaps;
    }

    private void AddButtonFunctionality(Dictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality> buttonFunctionality)
    {
        AddFunctionalityForShortPress(buttonFunctionality);
        AddFunctionalityForMediumPress(buttonFunctionality);
        AddFunctionalityForVeryLongPress(buttonFunctionality);
    }

    private void AddFunctionalityForVeryLongPress(Dictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality> buttonFunctionality)
    {
        // Get v
        int veryLongPress = _instrumenrData.GetValue(1); // gets the data from the instrument itself

        // calls mapper to get the corresponding functionality
        ButtonFunctionality functionality = InstructionButtonFunctionalityMapper.Mapper["InstrumentButtonType1" + veryLongPress];
        buttonFunctionality.Add(ButtonAction.ShortPress, functionality);
    }

    private void AddFunctionalityForMediumPress(Dictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality> buttonFunctionality)
    {
        int mediumPress = _instrumenrData.GetValue(2); // gets the data from the instrument itself

        // calls mapper to get the corresponding functionality
        ButtonFunctionality functionality = InstructionButtonFunctionalityMapper.Mapper["InstrumentButtonType1" + mediumPress];
        buttonFunctionality.Add(ButtonAction.MediumPress, functionality);
    }

    private void AddFunctionalityForShortPress(Dictionary<ButtonAction, ButtonFunctionality> buttonFunctionality)
    {
        int shortPress = _instrumenrData.GetValue(3); // gets the data from the instrument itself

        // calls mapper to get the corresponding functionality
        ButtonFunctionality functionality = InstructionButtonFunctionalityMapper.Mapper["InstrumentButtonType1" + shortPress];
        buttonFunctionality.Add(ButtonAction.ShortPress, functionality);
    }

    public override bool IsAvailable()
    {
        // checks some logic and returns tru or false
        return true;
    }

    public override bool IsEnable()
    {
        // checks some logic and returns tru or false
        return true;
    }
}

public static class InstructionButtonFunctionalityMapper
{
    private static Dictionary<string, ButtonFunctionality> _mapper;
    public static Dictionary<string, ButtonFunctionality> Mapper
    {
        get
        {
            return _mapper ?? (_mapper = FillMapper());
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, ButtonFunctionality> FillMapper()
    {
        var mapper = new Dictionary<string, ButtonFunctionality>
        {
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "VeryLongPress" + "0", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction1},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "VeryLongPress" + "1", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction2},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "VeryLongPress" + "2", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction3},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "0", ButtonFunctionality.ProgramDown},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "1", ButtonFunctionality.ProgramUp},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "2", ButtonFunctionality.VolumeDown},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "3", ButtonFunctionality.VolumeUp},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "4", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction1},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "5", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction4},
            {"InstrumentButtonType1" + "6", ButtonFunctionality.DoAction5}
        };


        return mapper;
    }
}

public enum ButtonFunctionality
{
    VolumeUp,
    VolumeDown,
    ProgramUp,
    ProgramDown,
    DoAction1,
    DoAction2,
    DoAction3,
    DoAction4,
    DoAction5
}

public enum ButtonAction
{
    ShortPress,
    MediumPress,
    LongPress,
}

public enum ButtonType
{
    PushButton,
    Volume
}
```

Thank you very much !!

Comment: You might be better served posting a question like this to the Code Review site. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to avoid "Magic numbers" like 1,2 etc. Use enum or constants instead.
2. Try to use explicit enum value like ShortPress = 0 ... It doing code more readable.
3. "InstrumentButtonType1" should be constant.
4. AddFunctionalityForMediumPress, AddFunctionalityForShortPress...  have same behaviour. Better way is creating one method AddFunctionalityForPress and put different values as parameters.
5. AddButtonFunctionality, AddFunctionalityForShortPress do these methods as extension methods.  And then you can see logic sequence like buttonFunctionality.AddButtonFunctionality(short).AddButtonFunctionality(long) ... etc.